# TypeError with Numba when averaging rows in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numba

I want to take the average of all the rows in a frame and print out the list as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time
from numba import jit

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

@jit(nopython=True)
def test(frame):
    print(frame.mean(axis=1))     # to take the mean of each row
        
fc = 0
frame_rate = 30
prev = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    time_elapsed = time.time() - prev
    if time_elapsed > 1/frame_rate:
        prev = time.time()
        if ret == True:
            
            cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
            print(frame.shape)   #(480, 640, 3)
            
            test(frame)
            
            if cv2.waitKey(27) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        # if no frame found
        else:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I keep getting the following error. Numba should work perfectly fine with numerical computations like averaging a numpy array, so I am a little confused about the issue with my function.

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
AssertionError()
- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
AssertionError()

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.mean for array(uint8, 3d, C))
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-2-3d43e63d267e> (11)


File "<ipython-input-2-3d43e63d267e>", line 11:
def test(frame):
    print(frame.mean(axis=1))     # to take the mean of each row
```

Comment: You can try `np.mean(frame,axis=1)` than the error message makes more sense (axis keyword unsupported). So you have to implement it yourself. Printing and measuring performance also doesn't make sense (printing is very costly). I guess your last dimension always has the size 3, right? This is a important point for an optimized solution.

Comment: I guess I should just manually go through each row of the frame and average it up

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments `np.mean` is only supported without any keywords. [supported functions](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions). You can quite easily implement it yourself, but if you have some more information about the real problem it is straight forward to optimize it even further.

**General solution**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mean_gen(frame):
    res=np.zeros((frame.shape[0],3),dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
        for j in range(frame.shape[1]):
            for k in range(frame.shape[2]):
                res[i,k]+=frame[i,j,k]
    return res/frame.shape[1]
```

**Solution if the last dimension is always of size 3**

```
In this case the inner loop can be unrolled to get better performance. The assertion `assert frame.shape[2]==3` is not only safety (there is no bounds checking), but also informs the compiler about the exact memory layout, which is often necessary for SIMD-vectorization. Some basic experience in C helps a lot in writing efficient code in Numba.

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=False)
def mean_3(frame):
    assert frame.shape[2]==3
    res=np.empty((frame.shape[0],3),dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(frame.shape[0]):
        acc1=0.
        acc2=0.
        acc3=0.
        for j in range(frame.shape[1]):
            acc1+=frame[i,j,0]
            acc2+=frame[i,j,1]
            acc3+=frame[i,j,2]
        res[i,0]=acc1/frame.shape[1]
        res[i,1]=acc2/frame.shape[1]
        res[i,2]=acc3/frame.shape[1]
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
#generate some date
frame=np.random.rand(1280,720,3)*255
frame=frame.astype(np.uint8)

#Numpy
%timeit np.mean(frame,axis=1)
#17.6 ms ± 557 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit mean_gen(frame)
#2.27 ms ± 22.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit mean_3(frame)
#606 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```